# How to mask javascript prompt() input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, impromptu, password-prompt

I'm using the "[Secure Profile](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-profile/eddeeogaiodnhfkingpegpmhpdiifbgh)" extension for Google Chrome. Although this app lets me secure my browser via a password, the password field text is visible during input. I need to hide or mask the input. How can I do that?

Here's are the details about the extension source code found in the installation directory.

Plugin files placed in: `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\eddeeogaiodnhfkingpegpmhpdiifbgh\1.2_0\includes`

directory Structure: 
\background.html
\options.html
\images*.png (3 images)
\js\encryption.js

Here's the HTML for the background.html

```
<html>
  <script src="js\encryption.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Only called when the first window of this profile is opened
    try {
        var encPassword = localStorage["password"];
        if (encPassword != null && encPassword != "") {
            var password = prompt(chrome.i18n.getMessage("bg_EnterPass"));
            if (password == null || encPassword != MD5(password)) {
                chrome.windows.getCurrent(function (window){chrome.windows.remove(window.id)});
            }
        } else {
            alert(chrome.i18n.getMessage("bg_SetOptions"));
            chrome.tabs.create({url: "includes/options.html"});
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Secure Profile Error: " + err.description);
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Here's the HTML Source for the options.html

```
<html>
    <body onload="body_onload();">
        <script src="js\encryption.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var _strSaved;
            var _strPwdMatch;
            // Saves options to localStorage.
            function saveOptions() {
                var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
                if (document.getElementById("passwordConfirm").value == password) {
                    if (password == "")
                        localStorage["password"] = "";
                    else
                        localStorage["password"] = MD5(password);
                    // Update status to let user know options were saved.
                    var status = document.getElementById("status");
                    status.innerHTML = _strSaved;
                    status.style.display = "block";
                    setTimeout(function() {status.style.display = "none";}, 3000);
                } else {
                    alert(_strPwdMatch);
                    document.getElementById("password").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("passwordConfirm").value = "";
                }
            }
            function loadStrings() {
                _strSaved = chrome.i18n.getMessage("opt_strSaved");
                _strPwdMatch = chrome.i18n.getMessage("opt_pwdMatch");
                document.title = chrome.i18n.getMessage("opt_title");
                document.getElementById("lblSetPwd").innerHTML = chrome.i18n.getMessage("opt_setPwd");
                document.getElementById("lblPwd").innerHTML = chrome.i18n.getMessage("opt_lblPwd");
                document.getElementById("lblPwdConf").innerHTML = chrome.i18n.getMessage("opt_lblPwdConf");
                document.getElementById("btnSave").value = chrome.i18n.getMessage("opt_btnSave");
            }
            function passwordIsSecure(password) {
                if (password && password.length > 4){
                    if (password.match(/([0-9]|\[|\\|\^|\$|\.|\||\?|\*|\+|\(|\)|\{|\}|!|@|#|%|&|_|=|-|`|~|<|>|\/)/i))
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            function setSecurePhoto(password) {
                if (password == "")
                    document.getElementById("imgPassSet").src = "images/decrypted.png";
                else {
                    if (passwordIsSecure(password))
                        document.getElementById("imgPassSet").src = "images/encrypted.png";
                    else
                        document.getElementById("imgPassSet").src = "images/halfencrypted.png";
                }
            }
            function body_onload() {
                loadStrings();
                setSecurePhoto(localStorage["password"]);
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #status {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                background-color: #C0C0C0;
                opacity: 0.9;
                display: none;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                padding-top: 25%;
                text-align: center;
                font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
                font-size: xx-large;
            }
        </style>
        <div id="status"></div>
        <table id="setPassword">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">
                    <div id="lblSetPwd"></div>
                </th>
                <td rowspan="4">
                    <img id="imgPassSet" src="images/decrypted.png" width="50px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="lblPwd"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" id="password" onchange="setSecurePhoto(this.value);" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="lblPwdConf"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" id="passwordConfirm" onfocus="this.value='';" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="right">
                    <input type="button" onclick="saveOptions()" id="btnSave" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the javascript from the encryption.js

```
/**
*
*  MD5 (Message-Digest Algorithm)
*  http://www.webtoolkit.info/
*
**/

var MD5 = function (string) {

    function RotateLeft(lValue, iShiftBits) {
        return (lValue<<iShiftBits) | (lValue>>>(32-iShiftBits));
    }

    function AddUnsigned(lX,lY) {
        var lX4,lY4,lX8,lY8,lResult;
        lX8 = (lX & 0x80000000);
        lY8 = (lY & 0x80000000);
        lX4 = (lX & 0x40000000);
        lY4 = (lY & 0x40000000);
        lResult = (lX & 0x3FFFFFFF)+(lY & 0x3FFFFFFF);
        if (lX4 & lY4) {
            return (lResult ^ 0x80000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
        }
        if (lX4 | lY4) {
            if (lResult & 0x40000000) {
                return (lResult ^ 0xC0000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
            } else {
                return (lResult ^ 0x40000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
            }
        } else {
            return (lResult ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
        }
    }

    function F(x,y,z) { return (x & y) | ((~x) & z); }
    function G(x,y,z) { return (x & z) | (y & (~z)); }
    function H(x,y,z) { return (x ^ y ^ z); }
    function I(x,y,z) { return (y ^ (x | (~z))); }

    function FF(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
        a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(F(b, c, d), x), ac));
        return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
    };

    function GG(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
        a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(G(b, c, d), x), ac));
        return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
    };

    function HH(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
        a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(H(b, c, d), x), ac));
        return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
    };

    function II(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
        a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(I(b, c, d), x), ac));
        return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
    };

    function ConvertToWordArray(string) {
        var lWordCount;
        var lMessageLength = string.length;
        var lNumberOfWords_temp1=lMessageLength + 8;
        var lNumberOfWords_temp2=(lNumberOfWords_temp1-(lNumberOfWords_temp1 % 64))/64;
        var lNumberOfWords = (lNumberOfWords_temp2+1)*16;
        var lWordArray=Array(lNumberOfWords-1);
        var lBytePosition = 0;
        var lByteCount = 0;
        while ( lByteCount < lMessageLength ) {
            lWordCount = (lByteCount-(lByteCount % 4))/4;
            lBytePosition = (lByteCount % 4)*8;
            lWordArray[lWordCount] = (lWordArray[lWordCount] | (string.charCodeAt(lByteCount)<<lBytePosition));
            lByteCount++;
        }
        lWordCount = (lByteCount-(lByteCount % 4))/4;
        lBytePosition = (lByteCount % 4)*8;
        lWordArray[lWordCount] = lWordArray[lWordCount] | (0x80<<lBytePosition);
        lWordArray[lNumberOfWords-2] = lMessageLength<<3;
        lWordArray[lNumberOfWords-1] = lMessageLength>>>29;
        return lWordArray;
    };

    function WordToHex(lValue) {
        var WordToHexValue="",WordToHexValue_temp="",lByte,lCount;
        for (lCount = 0;lCount<=3;lCount++) {
            lByte = (lValue>>>(lCount*8)) & 255;
            WordToHexValue_temp = "0" + lByte.toString(16);
            WordToHexValue = WordToHexValue + WordToHexValue_temp.substr(WordToHexValue_temp.length-2,2);
        }
        return WordToHexValue;
    };

    function Utf8Encode(string) {
        string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
        var utftext = "";

        for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

            var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

            if (c < 128) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
            }
            else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }
            else {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }

        }

        return utftext;
    };

    var x=Array();
    var k,AA,BB,CC,DD,a,b,c,d;
    var S11=7, S12=12, S13=17, S14=22;
    var S21=5, S22=9 , S23=14, S24=20;
    var S31=4, S32=11, S33=16, S34=23;
    var S41=6, S42=10, S43=15, S44=21;

    string = Utf8Encode(string);

    x = ConvertToWordArray(string);

    a = 0x67452301; b = 0xEFCDAB89; c = 0x98BADCFE; d = 0x10325476;

    for (k=0;k<x.length;k+=16) {
        AA=a; BB=b; CC=c; DD=d;
        a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+0], S11,0xD76AA478);
        d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+1], S12,0xE8C7B756);
        c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+2], S13,0x242070DB);
        b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+3], S14,0xC1BDCEEE);
        a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+4], S11,0xF57C0FAF);
        d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+5], S12,0x4787C62A);
        c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+6], S13,0xA8304613);
        b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+7], S14,0xFD469501);
        a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+8], S11,0x698098D8);
        d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+9], S12,0x8B44F7AF);
        c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+10],S13,0xFFFF5BB1);
        b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+11],S14,0x895CD7BE);
        a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+12],S11,0x6B901122);
        d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+13],S12,0xFD987193);
        c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+14],S13,0xA679438E);
        b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+15],S14,0x49B40821);
        a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+1], S21,0xF61E2562);
        d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+6], S22,0xC040B340);
        c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+11],S23,0x265E5A51);
        b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+0], S24,0xE9B6C7AA);
        a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+5], S21,0xD62F105D);
        d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+10],S22,0x2441453);
        c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+15],S23,0xD8A1E681);
        b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+4], S24,0xE7D3FBC8);
        a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+9], S21,0x21E1CDE6);
        d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+14],S22,0xC33707D6);
        c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+3], S23,0xF4D50D87);
        b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+8], S24,0x455A14ED);
        a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+13],S21,0xA9E3E905);
        d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+2], S22,0xFCEFA3F8);
        c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+7], S23,0x676F02D9);
        b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+12],S24,0x8D2A4C8A);
        a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+5], S31,0xFFFA3942);
        d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+8], S32,0x8771F681);
        c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+11],S33,0x6D9D6122);
        b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+14],S34,0xFDE5380C);
        a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+1], S31,0xA4BEEA44);
        d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+4], S32,0x4BDECFA9);
        c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+7], S33,0xF6BB4B60);
        b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+10],S34,0xBEBFBC70);
        a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+13],S31,0x289B7EC6);
        d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+0], S32,0xEAA127FA);
        c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+3], S33,0xD4EF3085);
        b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+6], S34,0x4881D05);
        a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+9], S31,0xD9D4D039);
        d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+12],S32,0xE6DB99E5);
        c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+15],S33,0x1FA27CF8);
        b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+2], S34,0xC4AC5665);
        a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+0], S41,0xF4292244);
        d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+7], S42,0x432AFF97);
        c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+14],S43,0xAB9423A7);
        b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+5], S44,0xFC93A039);
        a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+12],S41,0x655B59C3);
        d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+3], S42,0x8F0CCC92);
        c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+10],S43,0xFFEFF47D);
        b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+1], S44,0x85845DD1);
        a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+8], S41,0x6FA87E4F);
        d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+15],S42,0xFE2CE6E0);
        c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+6], S43,0xA3014314);
        b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+13],S44,0x4E0811A1);
        a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+4], S41,0xF7537E82);
        d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+11],S42,0xBD3AF235);
        c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+2], S43,0x2AD7D2BB);
        b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+9], S44,0xEB86D391);
        a=AddUnsigned(a,AA);
        b=AddUnsigned(b,BB);
        c=AddUnsigned(c,CC);
        d=AddUnsigned(d,DD);
    }

    var temp = WordToHex(a)+WordToHex(b)+WordToHex(c)+WordToHex(d);

    return temp.toLowerCase();
}
```

I noticed the password prompt is being fired from this line:

`var password = prompt(chrome.i18n.getMessage("bg_EnterPass"));`

read about `.i18n.getMessage` on google developers site, but there was no mention on how to mask this text. That leaves only the `prompt()` javascript function, and I searched only for a way to mask this prompt, but couldn't find any solution. There are jQuery plugins but I couldn't get the desired output.I tried the [Impromptu Plugin](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/), but didn't know how to return value to the `var password` from the $.prompt(); function via that plugin.

Could someone help me? Or suggest a better alternative to this chrome extension?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mask the JavaScript `prompt()` event. It is a built-in feature of many browsers and has few to no options.

If you want a fully customizable prompt, I suggest building your own from HTML and using a password input like Ram suggested. There are many benefits to this including allowing the user to view other tabs while the prompt is open.

Comment: It's kind of the point to NOT let the user view other tabs.. But you're right, only a custom UI will work for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think,this is solution for your problem
Give input type password.

```
<input type='password'/>
```

Comment: That won't solve it.. cause I don't require the password masking in options.html, I'm trying to mask it in the `background.html` where it says: `var password = prompt(chrome....);`